# Is it possible to get L and U matrices from LU decomposition singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a regular matrix $A$ and it's lower and upper triangular matrices $L$, $U$ such that $LU = A$ (LU decomposition).

My question is - is it possible for $L$ and $U$ to be singular even if $A$ is regular?

Comment: We have $\det (A) = \det(LU) = \det (L) \cdot \det (U)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "regular"?

Comment: @Winther Oh, of course :-) Thank you - could you, please, provide an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @Jack invertible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is a square matrix with [$LU$ decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) $A = LU$ then by the [determinant product property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) $\det(BC) = \det(B)\cdot \det(C)$ we get

$$\det (A) = \det(LU) = \det(L)\cdot \det(U)$$

From this it follows that if $L$ or $U$ is singular (i.e. has vanishing determinant) then so is $A$ and if $A$ is singular then so is either $L$ or $U$.